# How to hide my api key from api-football?

Tags: javascript, html, hide, api-key

I am building a small football app. For this, I am using custom widgets from api-football.com and used my api-key to fetch the data. Fortunately, it works and I get the standings table. Now, I want to hide my api-key which is directly used in the html file.

Code

[image]

View

[image]

I tried for several days, watched many tutorials, even used netlify serverless functions. But I couldn't hide the api key.

Comment: why do you need your API key in the HTML in the first place? How about storing it in a `.env ` file?

Comment: This is a custom widget available in the website. I don't exactly know how to hide. I tried to store api key in a .env file, but don't know how to link it to the html file.

Comment: An API key is usually used when hitting an API endpoint. Why do you need a key to present in the HTML markup instead of inside your code?

Comment: My guess the widget is gathering information from an element with certain ID, so you'd need either see if the widget supports javascript initialization otherwise would have to modify the widget itself...